# Convexity of set $\{x\mid\operatorname{dist}(x,S) \leq \operatorname{dist}(x,T)\}$

Tags: convex-analysis

Is it possible to prove analytically the convexity of the set: $\{x\mid {\rm dist}(x,S) \leq {\rm dist}(x,T)\}$ where $S,T \subseteq \Bbb R^n$, and ${\rm dist}(x,S) = \inf\{\|x-z\|_2 \mid z \in S\}$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not true. For example take $S=\{ (x,0) : x \in \mathbb{R} \}$ and $T=\{ (0,1), (0,-1) \}$ subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $\{ x | d(x,S) \leq d(x,T) \}$ is not connected, so it cannot be convex. Maybe this is true with some further hypothesis on $S,T$ (for example they are connected, or convex)?

Answer (score 2):

In general this set is not convex.

For example, in $\mathbb{R}$, $S =\{−1, 1\}, T = \{0\}$, we have $\{x\mid \operatorname{dist}(x,S)\le \operatorname{dist}(x,T)\}=\{x\in \mathbb{R}\mid x\le -\frac{1}{2} \text{ or } x\ge \frac{1}{2}\}$, which clearly is not convex.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How you come up with -1/2 and 1/2? Could you please clarify:)?

Comment: @Thoth $S$ is two points. You can draw $S$ and $T$ on a line.